# What is the meaning of Eloquent's Model::query()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

Can anyone please explain in detail what Eloquent's `Model::query()` means?

Comment: it returns the query builder for the given model !

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Any time you're querying a Model in Eloquent, you're using the Eloquent Query Builder.  Eloquent models pass calls to the query builder using magic methods (__call, __callStatic).  `Model::query()` returns an instance of this query builder.

Therefore, since `where()` and other query calls are passed to the query builder:

```
Model::where()->get();
```

Is the same as:

```
Model::query()->where()->get();
```

Where I've found myself using Model::query() in the past is when I need to instantiate a query and then build up conditions based on request variables.

```
$query = Model::query();
if ($request->color) {
    $query->where('color', $request->color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Devon. Can you provide a reference of the documentation?

Comment: What documentation are you looking for exactly?  The query builder's?  You can look at the API documentation or the Model class itself to see what it returns.

Comment: Can we do Joins on this?

Comment: @Shulz I would recommend using the relation methods built into Eloquent than doing your own join with the eloquent model.  Otherwise, you can use the Query Builder as standalone and write a query that returns loosely typed objects

Comment: inorder to get the response use `$query->get()'`

Comment: Why there is no documentation for query() method in the Laravel documentation?