# What is difference between Eloquent's Model::query()->get() and Model::get()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I want to know that, what is difference between Eloquent's Model::query()->get() and  Model::get()?

```
Model::get();
```

and

```
Model::query()->get();
```

I want to know that, what is the benefit to use query() method?

Comment: It's the same thing, query() will return a new query builder

Comment: to explain further, when you call ::get() statically, laravel will internally call query() for you, and forward your get() call to the query builder, so `Model::get() == Model::query()->get()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of Eloquent's Model::query()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517203/what-is-the-meaning-of-eloquents-modelquery)

Answer (score 2):

`Model::get()` will call for the magic method on Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
```

which will create a new instance and call the magic method

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
```

which will return

```
return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
```

And then the `->get()` method will be called on the resulting Query builder instance

While `Model::query()` will call

```
public static function query()
{
    return (new static)->newQuery();
}
```

and return a query builder instance skipping the magic method steps.

The big difference is that `Model::query()` is statically declared and more IDE friendly so type hinting will work correctly with it.